# how to add windows system path with python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I want to add folder to the windows path with python. I tried add folder with this codes.

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.system('setx /M path "%path%;'+path+'"')
```

this code output is =>

> ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.

and I tried this code

```
os.environ['PATH'] += path
```

When I print this code, it prints the environment variables on the screen, but when I open the environment variables page, this value does not appear.
How do I add this file path?

thanks.

Comment: Never do this. setx.exe is not meant for modifying `PATH`. This environment variable is the union of the system value and a per-user path, both of which are `REG_EXPAND_SZ` variables that are intentionally defined in terms of other variables. What you're doing is making a mess of the system "Path" value on both levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the error which is:

```
ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.
```

So, my suggestion would be running your program with the elevated permission.
You can do so my using is 'admin' module

```
import admin
if not admin.isUserAdmin():
    admin.runAsAdmin()
```

And try running your code as admin user

Comment: I restarted the computer. No problem